# Paperclip does not show image but instead shows title with amazon s3 in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am using paperclip and amazon s3 to store images for my website. Everything is working correctly without s3 in development mode but when I try to use s3 it shows me the title of the image and not the image. I have copied what is in the heroku guide https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3.

This is the gemfile

```
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.3'
```

this is in profile.rb in class profile

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
                       :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
                       :default_url => ":style/missing.jpg"
    validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

this is in production.rb

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_host_name: "s3-#{ENV['AWS_REGION']}.amazonaws.com",
    :s3_protocol => :https,
    s3_credentials: {
      bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
      access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
      secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
      s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
    }
  }
```

views

```
<%= image_tag @user.profile.avatar.url(:medium) %>
```

i have copied the heroku guide and added the host name and s3 protocol bit. whats wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed the heroku guide and was successfully able to upload the user image to S3 using paperclip in development env and I can also see the image in users's profile.

My **Gemfile**:

```
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk-s3'
```

My **development.rb**

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
storage: :s3,
s3_host_name: "s3.#{ENV['AWS_REGION']}.amazonaws.com",
s3_protocol: :https,
s3_credentials: {
    bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
    access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
  }
}
```

**you have this (this might have caused an issue):**

```
s3_host_name: "s3-#{ENV['AWS_REGION']}.amazonaws.com",
```

**I have this (a dot after s3):**

```
s3_host_name: "s3.#{ENV['AWS_REGION']}.amazonaws.com",
```

My **user.rb** is same as yours

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
                       :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
                       :default_url => ":style/missing.jpg"

# Validate the attached image is image/jpg, image/png, etc
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

My **show.html.erb**

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:medium) %>
```

I am using rails 5.2 version and with above code it works for me. Also do check whether your S3 bucket has public access to objects.

Comment: Hi, when I did what you did it says LoadError (cannot load such file -- aws-sdk (You may need to install the aws-sdk gem)): which is why i changed the gem back to gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.3' but then it shows me the same error and the picture doesnt show but the title does. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also, when i check my bucket it the image is there!

Comment: I made everything public and now this works. But is it dangerous to make it all public?

Comment: It is dangerous to make your S3 bucket public for writes, updates and deletes. You may also restrict write access to your bucket only via programmatic mode ( one who has key-pair can only modify. It is achieved via IAM policies ). For read operation it depends whether you want to secure your images / data from public access. There are various ways you can secure your s3 resources. Check out this link  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/secure-s3-resources/